# accessing elements through sparse matrix in scipy

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I have below code in python

```
# dense to sparse
from numpy import array
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
# create dense matrix
A = array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]])
print(A)
# convert to sparse matrix (CSR method)
S = csr_matrix(A)
print(S)
# reconstruct dense matrix
B = S.todense()
print(B)
```

Above code when I have following statement I have

```
print(B[0])
```

I have following output:

```
[[1 0 0 1 0 0]]
```

How can I loop through the above values i.e, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0

Comment: `S` is a `sparse matrix`.  `B` is dense `np.matrix`, with shape (1,6).  `A=S.A` (or `A=S.toarray()`) will make a dense `ndarray`, though it will still be (1,6) shape.  `np.matrix` will always be 2d.  `A[0]` will be (6,), 1d array.

Comment: How have you tried to loop, and problems do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [2]: from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
   ...: # create dense matrix
   ...: A = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]])
   ...: S = csr_matrix(A)
In [3]: A
Out[3]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]])
In [4]: S
Out[4]: 
<3x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

`S.toarray()` or `S.A` for short, makes a dense ndarray:

```
In [5]: S.A
Out[5]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]])
```

`todense` makes a `np.matrix` object, which is **always** 2d

```
In [6]: S.todense()
Out[6]: 
matrix([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]])
In [7]: S.todense()[0]
Out[7]: matrix([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
In [9]: S.todense()[0][0]
Out[9]: matrix([[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

To iterate by 'columns' we have to do something like:

```
In [10]: [S.todense()[0][:,i] for i in range(3)]
Out[10]: [matrix([[1]]), matrix([[0]]), matrix([[0]])]
In [11]: [S.todense()[0][0,i] for i in range(3)]
Out[11]: [1, 0, 0]
```

There is a shortcut for converting a 1d row `np.matrix` to a 1d `ndarray`:

```
In [12]: S.todense()[0].A1
Out[12]: array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

Get a 1d array from a "row" of a `ndarray` is simpler:

```
In [14]: S.toarray()[0]
Out[14]: array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

`np.matrix` is generally discouraged, as a remnant from a time when the transition from MATLAB was more important.  Now that fact that `sparse` is modeled on `np.matrix` (but not subclassed) is the main reason for keeping `np.matrix`.  Row and column sums of a sparse matrix return dense matrix.